# Construct a binary tree and traverse it in pre-order

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Let's say i need to build this tree from the digits `61207895` and then perform a pre-order traversal of the tree.

```
         6
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     1       7
    / \     / \
   0   2   5   8
                \
                 9
```

The expected result would be: `6 1 0 2 7 5 8 9`

But my code outputs: `6 1 0 2 5 7 8 9`

For some reason the position of digits `5` and `7` is switched. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    char* digits = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Digits:");
    scanf("%s", digits);

    Node* node = createNode(digits[0] - '0');

    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(digits); i++)
    {
        insertNode(node, digits[i] - '0');
    }
    free(digits);

    printf("Pre-order Traversal: ");
    preorderTraversal(node);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my function to insert nodes in the tree:

```
Node* insertNode(Node* node, int data)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (data < node->data)
        {
            node->left = insertNode(node->left, data);
        }
        else
        {
            node->right = insertNode(node->right, data);
        }
        return node;
    }
    else
    {
        return createNode(data);
    }
}
```

And this is my function to perform the Pre-order Traversal:

```
void preorderTraversal(Node* node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        preorderTraversal(node->left);
        preorderTraversal(node->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char* digits = malloc(sizeof(char));` ===> `digits` is only long enough for just the empty string!! You cannot hold `"61027589"` in there!!

Comment: @pmg When I ran the code, `char* RA = malloc(sizeof(char))` was able to store the entire string, but anyway, I edited it to `char* RA = malloc(8 * sizeof(char))`.

Comment: `8` bytes is not enough for `"61027589"`. You need to account for the terminating zero byte!!

Comment: @pmg edited again.

Comment: @SupportUkraine This is a homework I need to do for my course. The professor wrote in the question that we should build this tree from these digits, following the rule `"Whenever new data is to be added to the tree, it will be compared to the root node. If it is smaller than the root, it must be added to the left sub-tree, otherwise the right sub-tree"`. In the example given by him, with the digits `61207895` the tree and the result should be the ones I wrote in the post. But the tree I end up with is the one pointed out by @pmg.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yeah, I thought the question had a problem. But in my mind, the chance that I got something wrong was greater than the chance that the professor wrote a bug. Apparently I was wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you end up with

```
         6
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     1       7
    / \       \
   0   2       8
        \       \
         5       9
```